# function that takes a list of strings and prints them, one per line, in a rectangular frame

Tags: javascript, reactjs

13. Write a function that takes a list of strings and prints them, one per line, in a rectangular frame. For example the list ["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"] gets printed as:

```
    *********
    * Hello *
    * World *
    * in    *
    * a     *
    * frame *
    *********
```

my code

```
    var x = "hello\nworld\nin\na\nframe";

function star(str) {
  let arr = [];
  arr = str.split("\n");
  for (let index = 0; index < 1; index++) {
    console.log("*******");
    for (let j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++) {
     arr == arr[j].split(",");
      console.log("*" + arr[j] + "*" );
    }
  }
  console.log("******");
  return arr;
}
console.log(star(x));
```

Comment: at first, try to solve this by self. And paste here code, which you stuck on. This portal is not for solving your homeworks

Comment: I tried but it shows an error

Comment: is this a question?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, but I'm sure there are better ways.

```
function makeStarBox(arr){
  const longest = arr.reduce((a, b) => a.length <= b.length ? b : a);
  const box_width = longest.length + 2;
  
  console.log("*".repeat(box_width));

  arr.map(str => console.log("*" + str + " ".repeat(box_width - (str.length + 2)) + "*"));

  console.log("*".repeat(box_width));
}
```

It does seem like you are posting an actual homework/exam question though, so make sure to study the code and learn for yourself what it actually does. If you don't know what `map`, `reduce` or `repeat` does, check out the documentation and learn:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat